# Why does this loop only push one button?

Tags: javascript, closures

Why `this.buttons` have only one button pushed? The same problem with `this.element` - it has only the last button added to it.

```
this.initialize = function(buttonsCount) {
  for (var i = 0; i < buttonsCount; i++) {
    var btn = new ToolBarButton("btn" + i, null);
    this.buttons.push(btn);
    this.element.insertBefore(btn.element, this.element.lastChild);
  }
};
```

Comment: You already added `closure` tag to your question so why not learn how closures work? Hint: You can wrap the code in an IIFE and pass `i` as a param value to that function

Comment: I have read many times about them. I understand exapmples but not the general principal, and the exaples are never what I need for my project. I think my problem is 'i don't understand how the code executes'. I' from c# background and already hate javascript... No matter how much i read it doesn't help. I'm missing smth more basic than closures.